# Forcing a Sorting Direction? dir=asc&order=popularity

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, template

I want to disable a sorting direction for sort field. "Relevance" is a good example. Ordering by least-relevant results gives the most horrible results. Basically I want to disable that option.

The reason is because Sort Direction somewhat sticky in the user experience and I don't want users viewing our most relevant results and thinking, "wow - this is bad search".

Where would I disable "ASC" or rewrite as "DESC" when order=relevance

Something like this maybe?? Just don't know where.

```
if($order == 'relevance') { $dir = "DESC"; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

If you are looking for a quick and dirty way to override the sort direction, this is it. Doing it this way might be creating some bad UX as they might not understand why their results are not changing. The better way would probably be to make some JS that would prevent a customer from being able to choose this as an option.

### config.xml:

```
<catalog_controller_category_init_after>
    <observers>
         <SwiftOtter_Test>
              <class>SwiftOtter_Test_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>catalogControllerCategoryInitAfter</method>
         </SwiftOtter_Test>
    </observers>
</catalog_controller_category_init_after>
```

### Model/Observer.php:

```
const PARAM_DIR = 'dir';
const PARAM_ORDER = 'order';

public function catalogControllerCategoryInitAfter($observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
    $category = $observer->getCategory();

    /** @var Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action $action */
    $action = $observer->getControllerAction();

    $request = $action->getRequest();

    $dir = $request->getParam(self::PARAM_DIR);
    $order = $request->getParam(self::PARAM_ORDER);

    // Or, whatever logic goes here:
    if ($dir == 'desc' && $order == 'position') {
        $request->setParam(self::PARAM_DIR, 'asc');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain this is the right event? `catalog_controller_category_init_after`

Comment: I tested the code out (thus the `SwiftOtter_Test` namespace in the config.xml). The event is dispatched in `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->_initCatagory()`.

Comment: When. I tested it, the event triggered on the category view but not the search results view. Would it make a difference that I'm using EE with Solr?

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I didn't know you were looking for the search, too. Here is the event for that: `controller_action_predispatch_catalogresult_search_index`. Point that at the same observer, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I found this to work : `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index`

Comment: The problem I'm finding with `setParam(self::PARAM_ORDER, 'order');` is that the very next choice.. the `order` is built into the path.. `/catalogsearch/result/index/dir/asc/order/product_views/?dir=asc&order=name`   This isn't normal functionality and the parameter information in the route overrides the url parameters.

Comment: `setParam(self::PARAM_ORDER,'position')` solved the problem with the results but it effects all the urls on the page by injecting the parameters in to the url-path.. /path/order/position/