# Append Url Query Parameters to Request without affecting the url path?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

If requesting `/catalogsearch/result/index?q=search-term` and the query parameters `dir` and `order` aren't specified, I'd like to append them ( example? `$request->setParam('dir','asc');` ) to the requesting query string so that they can effect the search results page request.

My [previous question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15573/forcing-a-sorting-direction-dir-ascorder-popularity) figured out how to do this partially. The problem seems to be that the URL Path is affected?

The base path turns into `/catalogsearch/result/index/dir/[dir-value]/order/[order-value]/`

instead of remaining `/catalogsearch/result/index`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from the predispatch event. Here's the xml for the event hook:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index>
            <observers>
                <wordpress>
                    <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalogsearchResultIndexPredispatch</method>
                </wordpress>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index>
    </events>
</global>
```

And the observer model:

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogsearchResultIndexPredispatch()
    {
        Mage::getFrontController()->getRequest()->setParam('dir','asc');
        return $this;
    }

}
```